# Finding the max value in a specific column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to find the max value under column "Climate change (kg CO2 eq.)" which is 1 but when I use `scaled_df["Climate change (kg CO2 eq.)"].max()` I get the answer to be `0.9999999999999999`. How can I get the exact number?

Note: My dataset is very big, I've only provided a portion of it.

```
Part's Orientation (Support's volume) (cm^3)    Climate change (kg CO2 eq.) Climate change, incl biogenic carbon (kg CO2 eq.)   Fine Particulate Matter Formation (kg PM2.5 eq.)    Fossil depletion (kg oil eq.)   Freshwater Consumption (m^3)    Freshwater ecotoxicity (kg 1,4-DB eq.)  Freshwater Eutrophication (kg P eq.)    Human toxicity, cancer (kg 1,4-DB eq.)  Human toxicity, non-cancer (kg 1,4-DB eq.)  Ionizing Radiation (Bq. C-60 eq. to air)    Land use (Annual crop eq. yr)   Marine ecotoxicity (kg 1,4-DB eq.)  Marine Eutrophication (kg N eq.)    Metal depletion (kg Cu eq.) Photochemical Ozone Formation, Ecosystem (kg NOx eq.)   Photochemical Ozone Formation, Human Health (kg NOx eq.)    Stratospheric Ozone Depletion (kg CFC-11 eq.)   Terrestrial Acidification (kg SO2 eq.)  Terrestrial ecotoxicity (kg 1,4-DB eq.)
0   0.210866    0.040430    1.0 0.0 0.00    0.666667    0.040088    0.063802    0.040013    0.083205    0.005648    0.113808    0.104798    0.086400    0.108284    0.007368    0.091120    0.108676    0.090401    0.087426    0.101706    0.079028    0.080495    0.078380    0.082404    0.029502
1   0.210866    0.040430    1.0 0.2 0.00    0.666667    0.036597    0.038086    0.016068    0.074884    0.002636    0.045640    0.102285    0.082884    0.043371    0.003107    0.086700    0.105749    0.087161    0.084130    0.048885    0.072878    0.073529    0.074829    0.075438    0.011870
2   0.210866    0.044796    1.0 0.4 0.00    0.666667    0.031013    0.030436    0.008507    0.073035    0.001883    0.023401    0.102914    0.082494    0.022264    0.001854    0.086279    0.105749    0.086937    0.084130    0.032152    0.071341    0.071981    0.074698    0.073447    0.006456
3   0.210866    0.044311    1.0 0.6 0.00    0.666667    0.031013    0.026693    0.004883    0.072111    0.001506    0.012936    0.102914    0.082103    0.012289    0.001103    0.086069    0.105423    0.086602    0.084130    0.023950    0.070572    0.071207    0.074435    0.072452    0.003748
4   0.210866    0.045281    1.0 1.0 0.00    0.666667    0.031711    0.023438    0.001260    0.071803    0.001883    0.002180    0.103542    0.082884    0.002024    0.000601    0.086490    0.106074    0.087049    0.084542    0.015748    0.070572    0.071207    0.074961    0.072452    0.001249
```

Comment: add round() function after max(). `scaled_df["Climate change (kg CO2 eq.)"].max().round()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I get the exact number?

That *is* the exact number, it is completely accurate.

Suppose you had three observations of one-tenth.
You apparently performed a computation like this:

```
scale_factor = (.1 + .1 + .1) / .3
```

with the expectation that it would result in 1.0.

But the [FP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) quantity `.1`, with 53 bits of significand,
is quite different from the rational number 1 divided by 10.
It is impossible to represent the repeating digits
(repeating bits, similar to repeating decimals)
in a finite mantissa, so IEEE-754 computations are
not going to give the result you hoped for.

Let's try it in python:

```
>>> (.1 + .1 + .1) / .3
1.0000000000000002
>>>
```

Is that result "wrong"?
No. The machine correctly computed exactly what we asked for.

It sounds like you have a requirement for calling `.round( ... )`
on the results you compute.

Comment: Perfectly valid points about the imprecision of binary floating point, but I suspect part of the question is that if the actual value is 0.9999999 why does it show as 1.0 in the dataframe but as the actual value with `.max()` ?

Comment: Would you guys mind if you provide your valuable feedbacks to my other question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73921306/de-normalization-and-multiplying-a-data-frame-column-by-equation